# VB.NET: Nesting "Using" for database access

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, using

I'm wondering if this is a good way of doing data access, in terms of all the database objects being properly closed and disposed? For example:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
  Using cmd As New SqlCommand("some SQL here", conn)
    ... add parameters ...
    conn.Open()
    Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      While dr.Read()
        ... do stuff ...
      Wend
    End Using
  End Using
End Using
```

Is nesting `Using` like acceptable practice? If I exit the method at some point within the Read() loop, will the use of `Using` like this ensure all objects are cleaned up properly regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Using` guarantees orderly disposal in an implicit `try/finally` block.

```
' THE FOLLOWING TRY CONSTRUCTION IS EQUIVALENT TO THE USING BLOCK
Dim resource As New resourceType
Try 
    ' Insert code to work with resource.
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Insert code to process exception.
Finally 
    ' Insert code to do additional processing before disposing of resource.
    resource.Dispose() 
End Try
```

Nested usings work in a similar fashion.  If you exit a block of code, it will execute the `finally` block, and properly dispose your objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/htd05whh(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: I never knew that the using statement was essentially a try/finally. I have always just used try/catch/finally to dispose of my connections. +1 for the helpful tip.

Comment: Sounds good.. does it still apply if I explicitly exit the method at any point? eg. If my SQL is a `COUNT(*) FROM ...`, and I use the statement `Return cmd.ExecuteScalar()`. It will exit the method, before the `End Using`s, but will it still clean up?

Comment: Yes, it should fire all of the `finally` blocks, in proper order.

Answer (score 1):

To add, the Using block will "behind the scenes" add a Try Finally statement. In the finally statement it will call IDisposable.Dispose on the object. In other words, no matter what you do or what happens, the object will get disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is ok. The Dispose method of IDisposable objects is always called.

PS: In this case, the Dispose method also contains the Close method.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing VB.Net, so this only partially applies, but for the C# folks out there using StyleCop, multiple [using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) like this will cause exception [2202 in StyleCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx).

There is a lengthy section at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) link of dissenting comments as to the usefulness of this rule in stylecop.

I will not make a judgment call as to whether you should heed StyleCops warnings for C# in your VB.Net code.

Comment: Thanks.. is nested Using's ill-advised, or is that just a quirk of StyleCop?

Comment: @ingredient_15939 I'm guessing the rule is in place mainly for third party [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) implementations. For MS code, like [SqlConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx), we are pretty safe assuming it follows proper disposal techniques/patterns, so you are probably fine having multiple using statements where the IDisposable objects are framework objects.